# Derive the canonical SOP Boolean expressions for each segment (from a to g) based on the truth table

Tags: boolean, expression, canonical-link

The truth table for the seven-segment display segments (a to g) based on the 2-bit input (s1, s0). We'll use the binary input to display decimal digits from 0 to 3:

[My Truth Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v3LP4.jpg)

I am confused on where to go from here.

I know the basics of writing it out as ABCDEF A!BCDEFG.... etc but I don't think that is what it is asking.